# Should I get in touch with the recruiter with respect to accepting a job offer?

Tags: professionalism, job-offer, recruitment, united-states, job-acceptance

Last Wednesday, I received a job offer from Company A. The recruiter from Company A and I communicated back and forth until we agreed to terms that I would accept.† Company A gave me until Monday to accept/reject said job offer.

However, the recruiter hasn't gotten a hold of me yet (and it is currently Tuesday). Should I get in touch with Company A's recruiter to accept this job offer?

† <sub>I am awating on the outcome of a more desirable job after two interviews with Company B. Company B let me know that they will inform me of a decision no later than Thursday. I would prefer to not lose the offer from Company A by accepting it, then change my mind if Company B provides an offer as I would have something lined up regardless.</sub>

Comment: Did the recruiter from Company A tell you they would get ahold of you to find out your decision?  Or did they just say they needed your answer by Monday(in which case it would be up to you to contact them in relation to accepting the job or not)?

Comment: That wasn't clear to me. They didn't specify either way. I asked if I could have the weekend to think it over, and they said that would be fine.

Comment: I would say in that case, it was probably your responsibility to call/email them and either accept or decline, so yes, you should probably get ahold of them ASAP.

Comment: † If possible, I would always try to ask Company A to give you time until Thursday and ask Company B to hurry because you have a pending offer. It´s bad manners to let Company A prepare all the paperwork and send away the other candidates and then jump off in the last minutes. Burning some bridges - and you often meet twice ...

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, it would be a good idea to get a hold of the recruiter at company A.  Even if the recruiter said they'd call you on Monday, if they haven't, it's a good idea to give them a call and just let them know either way, whether you accept the job or not.

They may have forgotten to call you back, or they may have assumed you'd call them and let them know, so either way, I'd contact them and let them know whether you plan to accept the job offer or not.  It shows initiative, and especially if you want the job, it shows them that you want it.

Comment: I just got a hold of the recruiter of Company A and she will come back to me with an offer letter and paperwork. Regarding Company B, that offer doesn't exist, and until it does, I will move forward with Company A (stalling on signing any paperwork until I know for sure about Company B). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I get in touch with Company A's recruiter to accept this job offer?

Most certainly you should get in touch, but not necessarily to accept if you're waiting on company B. Waiting until after the potentially perceived deadline (Monday) is never going to be a good idea.

> They didn't specify either way. I asked if I could have the weekend to think it over, and they said that would be fine

If the weekend was specified by you, I would imagine most people (if not the majority) would expect a response by sometime Monday.

> I am awaiting on the outcome of a more desirable job after two interviews with Company B. Company B let me know that they will inform me of a decision no later than Thursday.

If you interviewed with company B around the same time as A (a couple days after or especially before), then you should have asked for more time initially from A. This is why it is a great idea to always ask ahead of time when you will know something even before you leave the interview. Even if it were Monday, it would have been a great idea to ask for more time from A, but waiting until after potentially hurts your position.